# How to create files in adf mobile

Tags: java, file, mobile, oracle-adf

I am using this code to create some files on phone device, ex : txt, pdf...etc

```
    try
    {
        File file = new File("myfile.txt");
        if (file.createNewFile())
        {
            //throw new AdfException("crée", AdfException.INFO);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AdfException("non crée", AdfException.INFO);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        throw new AdfException(e.getMessage(), AdfException.INFO);
    }
```

but I have this error message: read only file system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create the files under your application folder

```
String dir = AdfmfJavaUtilities.getDirectoryPathRoot(AdfmfJavaUtilities.ApplicationDirectory);
String filePath= dir + "/myfile.txt";
try
    {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (file.createNewFile())
        {
            //throw new AdfException("crée", AdfException.INFO);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AdfException("non crée", AdfException.INFO);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        throw new AdfException(e.getMessage(), AdfException.INFO);
    }
```

Comment: thank you. Another question, how find phone name, or imei id with adf mobile

Comment: you welcome, if the answere fixed your issue please mark it as correct answer, also please ask other questions in separate post for the sake of organization.